# Выборка уникальных значений по нескольким полям

Tags: mysql

Добрый день!
Помогите составить запрос в базу mysql.
Дана таблица:

```html
|id|haracterictic_id| value |modification_id|
---------------------------------------------
|1 |        40      | Седан |     122       |
|2 |        40      | Пикап |     123       |
|3 |        39      |Автомат|     122       |
```

Нужно составить запрос так, чтоб искало по полям `haracterictic_id` и `modification_id` и находило точно значение, например:

**нужно найти значение поля `modification_id`, если известно, что `haracterictic_id` будет '40' и '39', а `value` будет 'Седан' и 'Автомат' соответственно**

Comment: `...WHERE modification_id IN (39, 40) AND value IN ('Седан', 'Автомат')`?  Условие `field IN (val1, val2...)` можно расписать как `(field = val1 or field = val2)`, тогда ваше условие примет вид `...WHERE (modification_id = 39 OR modification_id = 40) AND (value = 'Седан' OR value = 'Автомат')`

Comment: мне нужно точное совпадение по всем значениям, а не "или то или то"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вашу цель, то что то вроде:

```
select modification_id
  from tableX
 where (haracterictic_id, value) in( ('40','Седан'), ('39','Автомат') )
 group by modification_id
having count(1)=2
```

Значение count(1) в having должно быть равно количеству проверяемых условий, что бы выбрало именно те записи, у которых есть совпадения всех условий.

Comment: Спасибо, работает. А если усложнить задачу и добавить через left join еще одну таблицу `modification` и так же сделать поиск по ней

Comment: я так понимаю, что верно запрос построен? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e9bf9/2

Comment: @wstudiokiwi Надо смотреть конкретную ситуацию. Но вот если прямо в этот запрос по left доклеить еще одну таблицу, то количество записей это не изменит, если в той таблице будет находится 0 или 1 записей. так что возможно нужен будет не left а просто join что бы сработало только в том случае если во второй таблице запись найдена или вообще с другой стороны заходить...

Comment: @wstudiokiwi Посмотрел ваш fiddle. Ну в общем можно так, только слово left не нужно.

Comment: @wstudiokiwi Я вообще бы написал что то типа http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e9bf9/12  в принципе абсолютно то же самое и оптимизатор скорее всего абсолютно так же выполнять запрос будет. Лично мне оно просто кажется логичнее выглядящим :)

Answer (score 2):

Вот пример решения

`IN` можно использовать для нескольких объектов

## Таблицы

```
create table tt (`id` int,`haracterictic_id` int,`value` varchar(100),`modification_id` int );

INSERT INTO tt
    (`id` ,`haracterictic_id` ,`value` ,`modification_id`   )
VALUES
    (1, 40,'Седан',122),  
    (2, 40,'Пикап',123),
    (3, 39,'Автомат',122)

;
```

## Запрос

```
select * from tt

where ( haracterictic_id,value )  in ((40,'Седан'), (39,'Автомат'))
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d9b69/3)

Comment: В таком варианте http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d9b69/5 он тоже найден, то 1 запись, а не должно вообще ничего не найти, т.к. нет точного совпадения

Comment: Да я уже понял , что не правильно понял вопрос ( думал что нужно просто найти все модификации у которых сопадает хотя бы одна пара `haracterictic_id,value` )