# Операторы mysql

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте. Подскажите пожалуйста, какой оператор использовать для следующей выборки:

```
`id_pole` = '1' AND `yesno` = '2' ОПЕРАТОР `id_pole` = '6' AND `yesno` = '1' ОПЕРАТОР `id_pole` = '8' AND `fix` = '10'
```

Comment: Условие зависит от того, что вы хотите получить на выходе. вернее не условие (оно всегда OR или IN вместо него, ибо AND даст невозможное сочетание и ничего не найдет), а форма запроса. подозреваю, что вы хотите организовать поиск в EAV. Если это так, то вам понадобится что то типа https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/506498/. И если это действительно так, то уточните вопрос. приведите входные жанные и что вы желаете получить, тогда можно будет с чистой совестью закрыть его как дубль :)

Answer (score 1):

Судя по всему вы хотите использовать оператор `ИЛИ` в MySQL это оператор `OR`:

```
(`id_pole` = '1' AND `yesno` = '2')
OR (`id_pole` = '6' AND `yesno` = '1')
OR (`id_pole` = '8' AND `fix` = '10')
```

Comment: не или, а **и** нужно

Comment: Как тогда у вас может поле `id_pole` в одной записи принимать разные значения?

Comment: вот и мне такая мысль приходила... у меня динамическое добавление полей к характеристикам товара. ид поля и заданный параметр должен совпадать

Comment: Похоже у вас несколько характеристик хранится в одной таблице в разных записях вот вам и нужно достать все записи с помощью  `OR`. Если это не так, то обновите вопрос и приведите запрос полностью и данные которые вы хотите получить