# Как сформировать SQL запрос по двум ключам?

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть такая таблица

```
----------------------------
product | key    | values
----------------------------
60      | key_1  | "строка"
----------------------------
60      | key_2  | 25
----------------------------
```

Как сформировать запрос таким образом, что бы достать запись c проверкой по двум ключам

`key = 'key_1' AND values = 'строка' AND key = 'key_2' AND value >= 25`

То есть у нас должна выбраться запись которая имеет ключ `key_1` который равен `строка` и в тоже время имеет ключ `key_2` который равен (или меньше) `25`

Проще говоря это опции товара, и по ним надо делать фильтрацию. В данном примере у товара есть две опции и в данной таблице записаны значения этих опций, одна строковая другая число. Так вот надо что бы товар можно было вытащить если одно значение у него `"строка"` а другое значение больше или ровно `25`

Сделал вот так

```
SELECT * FROM `params` WHERE (params.key, params.value) IN( ('obrabotka','Топленое'), ('zhirnost', 25) )
```

Но вот эти части никак между собой не связаны

`('obrabotka','Топленое'), ('zhirnost', 25)`

В идеале было бы вот так

`('obrabotka','Топленое') AND ('zhirnost', 25)`

**Пример:**

Запрос

```
SELECT * FROM `params` WHERE params.key = 'obrabotka' AND params.value = 'Топленое'
```

Ответ

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Запрос

```
SELECT * FROM `params` WHERE params.key = 'zhirnost' AND params.value >= 25
```

Ответ

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как объединить эти два запроса что бы получилось что то такое ?

```
WHERE params.key = 'obrabotka' AND params.value = 'Топленое' AND params.key = 'zhirnost' AND params.value >= 25
```

Comment: Так ведь это две записи, а не одна. Покажите ожидаемый результат запроса

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/506498/ только вместо IN напишите два ваших критерия через OR

Comment: Ужас какой... Есть подозрение, что вам лучше использовать что-то из области noSql.

Comment: @Anatol ожидаемый результат как раз такой и должен быть. Представим что есть таких же две записи но у дрогой записи key_2 = 10

Comment: _UNION_ не подходит?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В иных СУБД это могло бы выглядеть так:

```
SELECT product
FROM params
WHERE params.key = 'obrabotka' AND params.value = 'Топленое' 
INTERSECT
SELECT product
FROM params
WHERE params.key = 'zhirnost' AND params.value >= 25 --только тут явно нужно value преобразовать в число
```

В MySQL медленный вариант будет выглядеть так:

```
SELECT *
FROM(
  SELECT product,
    MAX(IF(params.key = 'obrabotka', value, NULL))obrabotka,
    MAX(IF(params.key = 'zhirnost', value, NULL))zhirnost
  FROM params
  GROUP BY product
)T
WHERE obrabotka='Топленое' AND zhirnost >= 25 --только тут явно нужно value преобразовать в число
```

Если попробовать написать что-то более оптимальное с точки зрения производительности, можно поступить так:

```
SELECT *
FROM(
  SELECT product
  FROM params
  WHERE params.key = 'obrabotka' AND params.value = 'Топленое' 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT product
  FROM params
  WHERE params.key = 'zhirnost' AND params.value >= 25 --только тут явно нужно value преобразовать в число 
)T
GROUP BY product HAVING COUNT(*)=2
```

**UPD:** или даже так:

```
SELECT p1.product, p1.value obrabotka, p2.value zhirnost
FROM params p1
  JOIN params p2 ON p1.product = p2.product
WHERE p1.key = 'obrabotka' AND p1.value = 'Топленое' 
  AND p2.key = 'zhirnost' AND p2.value >= 25
```

Comment: Спасибо ! То что надо