# SQL WHERE запрос с проверкой нескольких значений

Tags: mysql, sql

Помогите, пожалуйста, составить запрос.

Есть таблица в БД (назовем **product_attribute**):

```
product_id | attribute_id | value
----------------------------------
1          | 1            | text
1          | 2            | 10
2          | 1            | text
2          | 2            | 20
3          | 1            | text
```

**Нужно выбрать** product_id в которых, например, attribute_id = 1  со значением "text" **И** attribute_id = 2  со значением "20" (т.е. **product_id = 2** в данном случае)

---

Напрашивается вот такой запрос:

```
SELECT `product_id` 
FROM `product_attribute` 
WHERE (`attribute_id` = 1 AND `value` = "text") AND (`attribute_id` = 2 AND `value` = 20)
```

Но, как вы понимаете он ничего не возвращает :) (т.к. attribute_id разные).

Надеюсь описал ситуацию понятно... Как быть, господа?

Comment: OR. GROUP BY. COUNT=2.

Comment: поменяйте `AND` на `OR` между скобок

Comment: @Mike Спасибо, то что надо

Comment: @Дмитрий тогда думаю надо согласится что это дубль. у вас там где то кнопка для этого должна быть (сам никогда ее не видел :) )

Comment: @Mike Вот и я не нахожу... Добавил ответ со ссылкой на тему

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from product_attribute
where ( attribute_id,value )  in ((1,'text'), (2,20))
group by product_id
having count(product_id)=2
```

Ответ из этой темы: [Выборка уникальных значений по нескольким полям](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/506498/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%bc)

Результат: [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2ed57b/8)

Answer (score 0):

Наверное все таки так:

```
SELECT `product_id` 
FROM `product_attribute` 
WHERE ((`attribute_id` = 1 AND `value` = "text") OR (`attribute_id` = 2 AND `value` = 20))
```

Comment: В том то и дело, что по условию нужно именно AND а не OR... В коментарии дали ссылку на похожий вопрос. Сейчас ковыряю. Впринципе там ответ правильный, вот только sql формируется динамически и прикрутить его с HAVING COUNT пока не понимаю как. Вот ссылка на верный ответ: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2ed57b/8

Comment: Просто у вас запрос вернет 2 значения, а должно вернуться одно.