# Запрос в базу MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть таблица проектов `projects`:

```
id | name
```

Есть таблица этапов `etapy` - здесь хранятся названия этапов:

```
id_etap | name_etap
```

И есть таблица `etapyinpro` - в которой хранятся данные о том в каком проекте какие есть этапы и выполнены они или нет:

```
id | id_pro | id_etap | status
```

`id_pro` - это ссылка на проект

`id_etap` - это ссылка на этап

`status` - выполнен или нет, если 1 - то выполнен, если 0 - то не выполнен.

Нужно написать запрос который будет выводить те проекты которые например имеют этап

```
id_etap = 1 и status = 1 и id_etap = 2 и status = 0 и id_etap = 3 и status = 0
```

Т.е. полное совпадение, если все эти этапы есть в проекте и если их статусы совпадают с условием то показываем, если например в каком-то проекте этапа с `id_etap = 3` вообще нет то не показываем.

Comment: А в чем, собственно, проблема?

Comment: select id_pro from etapyinpro where (id_etap = '1' and status='1') and (id_etap = '2' and status='1') group by  id_pro

Comment: Так не работает... Как правильно? В этом проблема...

Comment: конечно не работает, условие применяется к одной строке, и не может у вас `id_etap` быть  равным и 1 и 2 одновременно.

Comment: у вас 3 группы условий в трех строках будет. вот и посчитайте, сколько строк попадает под эти условия для каждого проекта. Если 3, то проект подходит. Но придется еще обойти условие с отсутствием 3го этапа, и это тут наиболее сложная часть

Comment: Пример можно? Если бы так хорошо разбирался в sql не задавал бы вопрос...

Comment: @194569 Mike помогите...

Comment: @Mike помогите плиз

Comment: Если записи с этапами гарантированно есть в таблице, только статусы у них соответственно 0 или 1 то практически идеально подходит такой https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/506507/194569 вариант. Если я конечно правильно понял вопрос, что надо подобрать то что имеет строго заданный набор этапов с строго заданными для каждого статусами. Хотя вроде IN в MS SQL так не работает, тогда равернуть его в `(id_etap = 1 and status = 1) OR (id_etap = 2 and status = 0)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

данный запрос выведет вам те проекты, в которых есть 3 этапа с заданными статусами:

```
select p.id, p.[name], count(*)
from
    projects p 
    inner join etapyinpro es ON p.id = es.id_pro
where 
    (es.id_etap = 1 and es.[status] = 1)
    OR (es.id_etap = 2  and es.[status] = 0)
    OR (es.id_etap = 3  and es.[status] = 0)
group by p.id, p.[name]
having count(*)=3
```

Comment: тем не менее этот запрос не решет вторую половину проблемы: _"если в каком-то проекте этапа с id_etap = 3 вообще нет то не показываем"_

Comment: @teran вы не правы - при отсутствии этапа 3 count(*) будет равен 2 и проект не попадет в выборку

Comment: а, действительно, я че то прочитал что "показываем", типа 3й  не обязательный.

Comment: вообще, мб стоило переформулировать вопрос так, чтобы вывести только те проекты, у которых завершен только первый этап

Comment: @teran без нормального описания задачи от автора сводить задачу к отображению только 1 завершенного этапа некорректно, т.к. в выборку попадут проекты без 2 и 3 стадии в принципе, а автору вопроса могут быть интересны проекты из 3 стадий

Comment: Спасибо! Ответ помог!!!!