# Объединение двух и более запросов

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть два (дальше будет больше) запроса,  производящих выборку по одной и той же схеме, но с разными входными данными. 
Вид запроса

```
SELECT DISTINCT list_ims.name 
FROM list_ims, measuring, test_name 
WHERE measuring.id_test = test_name.id 
    AND measuring.id_IMS=list_ims.id 
    AND test_name.name LIKE "%IIH%" 
    AND measuring.up_border<= 3
```

Входные данные меняются только в параметре `test_name.name` и верхней(либо нижней) границей. Все остальное идентично.
То есть условия по `up_border и down_border` идут к конкретному `test_name.name`, и логическими операторами не ищет то, что нужно. 
Собственно, не понимаю как составить запрос на пересечение двух селектов и отображению только тех данных, что содержатся и в первом, и во втором (и при необходимости третьи и т.д.).
Пробовал через `IN`, `UNION` (но первый не вывел ничего, второй наоборот - показал все и по первому и по второму, оставив не повторяющиеся данные).
Есть догадка через `INNER JOIN` делать, но не осознаю по какому ключу соединить.  Таблица же в итоге одна и та же.
На крайняк есть задумка через временные таблицы, но это явно совсем дичь и не хочется использовать.
Заранее, спасибо за помощь.

Comment: да, я понял, не заметил сразу слова "пересечение". Тогда что то в этом роде https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/506507/194569  вместо in с двумя условиями сразу делаете соответственно набор из условий по name и диапазону, через OR. если там какое то лишнее дублирование данных, то можно применять `count(distinct name)` или что то в этом роде

Comment: А могу ли я при перечислении условий писать не точные значения, а указывать ещё одно условие ? В плане, не `up_border` =5, а <=5?

Comment: я же говорю, разверните в обычные OR. как в любом языке программирования. `... AND ( (test_name.name LIKE "%IIH%" 
    AND measuring.up_border<= 3)  OR (test_name.name LIKE "%XXX%" 
    AND measuring.up_border<= 100500)  )`

Comment: Если слишком сложно так, конечно можно объединить два запроса через `union all` (обратите внимание на ALL), но потом все равно надо будет обернуть это в еще один запрос и сделать group by и подсчет. И да, в особо тяжелых случаях конечно можно сделать join двух запросов. А по какому ключу соединять (так же по какому полю группировать) не видя полной структуры с примером данных, кроме вас никто сказать не сможет. исходя из запроса выходит, что по `list_ims.name` (и возможно по нему надо заранее группировать, перед основной частью, раз у вас там distinct ...)

Comment: `SELECT q1.* FROM (запрос 1)  q1, (запрос 2) q2, (запрос 3) q3 ... WHERE q1.field=q2.field AND q1.field=q3.field ...`

Comment: @Mike добрался до базы. Попробовал сделать через логические операторы. Через AND между двумя условиями в ()  - возвращает пустую строку. Через OR - возвращает все сущности `list_ims.name` из таблицы `list_ims`

Comment: @Akina, не поясните что есть `q1.*` и `WHERE q1.field=q2.field ` в запросе?

Comment: @Depressa Конечно все, вы же вроде и хотели все, и те которые с одним условием и которые с другим. Остается их только сгруппировать и посчитать, что бы вынести решение было пересечение или они уникальны

Comment: @Mike, возможно опять не догоняю. Прошу простить. Если брать селекты по отдельности, то первый возвращает мне список:

    1002ИР1
    1554ИЕ19
    1554ТЛ2 
    533ЛИ1
    533ЛИ3
    533ЛЛ1
    533ЛН1
    533ТМ2
    5514БЦ1Т1-00
    5514БЦ1Т1-02
    1504ЛА3А

Второй в свою очередь:
    1554ИЕ19
    1554ТЛ2
    1504ЛА3А

По идее, объединение двух из них будет:
    1554ИЕ19
    1554ТЛ2
    1504ЛА3А

Comment: посмотрите самую первую ссылку, что я дал. там как раз выбираются записи с двумя разными условиями , потом группируются по общему полю и после этого в HAVING считается сколько записей было и если их столько же сколько условий, значит были все и значит это пересечение

Comment: `q1.*` есть список вывода. `WHERE q1.field=q2.field` есть условие отбора.

Comment: @Akina под `q1` подразумевается некая таблица, или что?

Comment: Ну посмотрите на запрос-то повнимательнее, да? `q1` - это алиас первого подзапроса.

Comment: @Mike если брать пример из ссылки, как в перечислении значений указывать LIKE и больше или равно/меньше или равно?

Comment: Условия в where и общий подход с группировкой и получением количества это совершенно разные вещи. оставляйте условия как у вас с OR. IN из того примера отлично разворачивается в `(haracterictic_id=40 and value='Седан') OR (haracterictic_id=39 and value='Автомат')`

Comment: И вообще, написание любого запроса SQL сводится к постепенному пути к цели. сначала делается выборка, которая дает все необходимые записи и ничего лишнего (т.е. пишутся правильные условия в where). когда она есть, смотрите на нее как на обычную таблицу и решаете, какие трансформации с данными из нее надо произвести