# Способ поиска по результатам анкетирования (по таблице многие ко многим)

Tags: mysql, sql

Структура кусочка базы данных представлена на скриншоте ниже. Связь между `people` и `questions` многие ко многим через таблицу `answers`. У каждого человека может быть разное количество ответов на вопросы - кто-то ответил на 4 вопроса, кто-то на все, а кто-то вообще ни на один. Ответ на вопрос хранится в поле `value` таблицы `answers`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос в том, как составить запрос на выборку людей по комбинированному условию. Например, людей которые одновременно:

- `answers.question_id = 2 and answers.value >= 2`
- `answers.question_id = 4 and answers.value < 2`

Т.е. как получить тех людей, которые ответили на второй вопрос >= 2 и при этом ответили на четвёртый вопрос < 2?

Предположил, что вот так (смотри ниже), но результатов нет (а они быть должны)

```
SELECT people.id,
       people.surname
  FROM people
 INNER JOIN answers
    ON answers.person_id = people.id
 WHERE (answers.question_id = 2
   AND answers.value >= 2)
   AND (answers.question_id = 4
   AND answers.value < 2)
```

Comment: Результатов у вас нет, потому что условие во `where` требует одновременно для одной строки выполнение условия `answers.question_id = 2 and answers.question_id = 4`, что не выполнится никогда

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Выборка уникальных значений по нескольким полям](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/506498/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%bc)

Comment: Так же как там ^^^, только IN раскройте в `(answers.question_id=2 and answers.value >= 2) OR (answers.question_id=4 and answers.value < 2)`

Comment: @Mike - так О_о? `where (question_id, answers) in((answers.question_id=2 and answers.value >= 2) OR (answers.question_id=4 and answers.value < 2) )`

Comment: Нет, просто `where (answers.question_id=2 and answers.value >= 2) OR (answers.question_id=4 and answers.value < 2)` главное же в запросе group by, и получение количества совпадений. Т.е. фактически в своем запросе меняете условие на OR что бы он выбирал и те и другие записи (в том числе те, у которых совпало только одно условие), после чего добавляете group by и having для ограничения на те записи, которые встретились дважды, т.е. по которым были совпадения обоих условий

Comment: @Mike работает. Хм.. А что такое count(1). Что оно считает? Первый столбец в результатах?

Comment: count() считает любые not null значения. значение 1 не NULL, значит он его посчитает :) Просто в некоторых СУБД оптимизаторы дурные и `count(*)` может дольше работать чем `count(1)`, так что это просто привычка

Comment: @Mike Спасибо! Я кажется понял)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь группировкой:

```
SELECT
  people.id,
  people.surname
FROM people
  INNER JOIN answers
    ON answers.person_id = people.id
WHERE (answers.question_id = 2
AND answers.value >= 2)
OR (answers.question_id = 4
AND answers.value < 2)
group by people.id, people.surname
having count(people.id) >= 2
```

т.е. если в группе получилось две строки - это означает что есть строка с `id=2` и `value >= 2`и `id=4` и `value < 2`

Comment: Это не работает - ноль результатов

Comment: Ну вы хоть думайте, что ли над предложенным ответом :-) `т.е. если в группе получилось две строки` - условие конечно же должно быть `>=2` Или вообще `= 2`

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT people.id,
       people.surname
FROM   people
LEFT   JOIN answers a1
ON     a1.person_id = people.id
AND    a1.question_id = 2
AND    a1.value >= 2
LEFT   JOIN answers a2
ON     a2.person_id = people.id
AND    a2.question_id = 4
AND    a2.value < 2
GROUP  BY people.id
HAVING MAX(a1.value) IS NOT NULL
AND    MAX(a2.value) IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Как идея. Не уверен, что сработает. Проверять нет времени

Comment: Вроде бы работает, но не совсем понимаю необходимость HAVING и того, что ниже. Как это работает?

Comment: @n.osennij `LEFT JOIN`, если для записи в *левой* таблице не нашлось совпадений, всё равно включит запись в результат, но поля присоединяемой (_правой_) таблицы напротив неё будут `NULL`'ами. Поэтому в `HAVING` такие случаи явно отброшены. `GROUP BY` же, вероятно, лишний (см. предположение у меня в ответе) и по всей строгости в нём не хватает `people.surname`. А в целом подход такой же, как у меня: взять таблицу людей и последовательно присоединить к ней множества подходящих ответов.

Answer (score 2):

Максимально наивная и наверняка медленная, зато максимально понятная реализация:

```
SELECT people.id, people.surname
FROM people
  JOIN answers a1
    ON a1.person_id = people.id
      AND a1.question_id = 2
      AND a1.value >= 2
  JOIN answers a2
    ON a2.person_id = people.id
      AND a2.question_id = 4
      AND a2.value < 2
```

Поскольку `JOIN` = `INNER JOIN`, в результат будут включены только люди, для которых нашлись такие ответы.

Я исхожу из предположения, что каждый человек может ответить на каждый вопрос не более одного раза; в противном случае один человек может попасть в результаты запроса несколько раз, если для него найдётся несколько пар подходящих ответов.

Comment: а чем это проще выбранного мною в качестве ответа на вопрос варианта ниже?

Comment: @n.osennij используется меньше концепций из SQL. Там join, group by и having, здесь же только join. Но я почти уверен, что мой вариант медленнее, и опубликовал его скорее для того, чтобы продемонстрировать присоединение одной и той же таблицы дважды; это некогда пригодилось мне в работе и разорвало один очень крепкий шаблон в голове.