# Поиск строки в предыдущей итерации

Tags: php, sql

```
$strFindInSet = 'FIND_IN_SET';
    $iteration = 0;
    foreach ($userRow["cur_hars"] as $key => $curHar) {

        if ($iteration == 0) {
            $strFindInSet = $strFindInSet . '(' . $curHar["value"] . ',`' . $curHar["id"] . '`' . ')';
        } else {
            $strFindInSet = $strFindInSet . ' AND FIND_IN_SET(' . $curHar["value"] . ',`' . $curHar["id"] . '`' . ')';
        }

        $iteration++;

    }
    $ifress = $db->rawQuery('SELECT * from alice5_ifress where ' . $strFindInSet . '');
```

Формирую запрос в цикле с FIND_IN_SET в котором устанавливаю необходимые характеристики для поиска, проблема в том что мне нужно проверять значение `$curHar["id"]`  текущей итерации со значением `$curHar["id"]` предыдущей итерации и если условие выполняется, то я пишу не AND, а OR и оборачиваю в скобки FIND_IN_SET предыдущей итерации и FIND_IN_SET текущей итерации, как такое вообще выполнить??? 
Т.е. получается что-то вроде:

```
SELECT * from alice5_ifress where FIND_IN_SET (55,`10`) AND FIND_IN_SET(76,`42`) AND FIND_IN_SET(80,`59`) AND ( FIND_IN_SET(53,`8`) OR FIND_IN_SET(83,`8`))
```

Comment: заводите переменную, скажем $last_id, сверяете с ней, подставляете нужное. в конце итерации делаете `$last_id=$curHar["id"]`. А вообще начать стоит с пересмотра структуры БД. явно напрашивается отдельная таблица, с примерной структурой (всего 3 поля): id-сущности из alice5_ifress, id-показателя (вот те ваши 10, 42, 8), значение (которые 76, 80, 53). работа станет на порядок проще и для вас и для mysql, весь запрос сведется к чему то такому https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/506507/194569

Answer (score -1):

Такое решается в 2 прохода. На первом идет группировка по `id`, а на втором уже формируем запрос

```
$clauses = [];
foreach ($array as $current) {
   $clauses[$current["id"]][] = 'FIND_IN_SET((' . $curHar["value"] . ',`' . $curHar["id"] . '`' . ')';
}

$where = '';
foreach($clauses as $clause) {
    if ($where) {
        $where .= " AND "; 
    }

    if (count($clause) > 0) {
        $where .= '(' . implode(' OR ', $clause) . ')';
    } else {
        $where .= $clause[0];

    }
}
```

**UPD**: исправил ответ после замечания

Comment: Спасибо за столь очевидный ответ, но проблема состоит не в том чтобы записать значение предыдущей итерации, а в том чтобы изменить строку запроса, сформированную в предыдущей итерации.

Comment: Точно, не внимательно прочитал вопрос. Чтобы реализовать то что вам нужно, просто это сделайте не в один проход, а в 2. В первый раз подготовьте структуру данных, а на втором уже формируйте запрос.