# Помогите составить запрос на выборку объявлений в mysql

Tags: mysql

для более наглядного представления проблемы опубликовал в sqlfiddle.

Сейчас работает такое решение
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/22730e/3
но это не вариант т.к. количество option_хх растет и их уже более 200

Мне нужно реализовать что то подобное
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b07c38/1

Помогите, буду очень благодарен

Comment: А задача какая? Что нужно выбрать?

Comment: *для более наглядного представления проблемы опубликовал в sqlfiddle.* Нет, Вы полностью распишите задачу ЗДЕСЬ. fiddle - это дополнение, не более того, пусть и очень полезное дополнение. Тем более что я вижу две ссылки на два fiddle с РАЗНЫМИ структурами.

Comment: Если ваш вопрос вдруг о выборе по нескольким условиям из структуры типа EAV, то вот https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/506498/194569