# SQL запрос на выборку складов

Tags: mysql, sql

Например, имеется много складов и таблица в которой каждая запись отражает на каком складе конкретный товар и сколько штук. Один товар может быть на нескольких складах.

Итого: таблица product_amounts. С полями: warehouse_id, product_id, amount. 
Нужен запрос, который бы выбрал из этой таблицы те склады на которых есть определенное кол-во товаров. Допустим, все склады, в которых есть товары с идентифкатором 1 в количестве 5 штук и с идентификатором 2 в количестве 2 штуки.

Хотелось бы одним запросом такое реализовать. Но что-то в голову не идёт ничего кроме как в цикле получить для каждого товара подходящие склады (WHERE product_id=1 and amount >= 5 , WHERE product_id=2 and amount >= 2) и потом оставить только те склады, которые есть и у того и у того. Но чувствую, что можно сделать это всё на SQL, возможно даже одним запросом. Может быть даже решение простое и я просто торможу.

Comment: Создайте fiddle и покажите желаемый результат для него. *имеется много складов и таблица в которой каждая запись отражает на каком складе конкретный товар и сколько штук* Объявлена ли пара (склад, товар) уникальной? Если нет, то наличие - это последняя по времени запись или сумма всех записей?

Comment: *чувствую, что можно сделать это всё на SQL, возможно даже одним запросом. Может быть даже решение простое* "Да" на все три вопроса.

Comment: Как тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/506507/194569 только вместо IN `(product_id=1 and amount >= 5) OR (product_id=2 and amount >= 2) ...`

Comment: склад-товар - да, уникальны. Наличие это колонка amount если 0 - то нет в наличие

Comment: @Mike большое спасибо, работает!

Comment: в вопросе чувствуется нехватка кода