# Сделать выборку по нескольким полученым данным

Tags: php, mysql, sql

делаю фильтр товаров, написал вот такой скрипт:

```
// Получаем данные формы
$cat_id = $_POST['cat_id'];
$get_ves = $_POST['f__ves'];  // Вес
$get_material = $_POST['f__material']; // Материал




// Получаем id товаров текущей категории
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `oc_product_to_category` WHERE category_id = '" . $cat_id . "' ";
$query = mysqli_query($dbh, $sql);
        $product_id_arr = array();
        while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
            $product_id_arr[] = $row['product_id'];
            
        }



// Выполняем запрос на получение товаров
        if ($product_id_arr) {
                foreach ($get_ves as $get_ves_item) {
                    foreach ($product_id_arr as $prod_id) {

                     $prod_get_attr = "SELECT * FROM `oc_product_attribute` WHERE product_id = '" . $prod_id . "' AND attribute_id = '" . 28 . "' AND text = '" . $get_ves_item . "'"; // получаем id товаров, выбранных атрибутов Вес
                     $query_prod_get_attr = mysqli_query($dbh, $prod_get_attr);
                     

                     foreach ($query_prod_get_attr as $product_id) {
                        $product_val[] = $product_id['product_id']; 
                    }
                    
                }
                
            }
            var_dump($product_val);
        }
```

Скрипт работает сйечас по $get_ves.
Не понятно, как сделать выборку по нескольким полученым данным методом POST, к примеру если будет получен еще и material ($get_material).
Думаю можно написать как то так:

```
"SELECT * FROM `oc_product_attribute` WHERE product_id = '" . $prod_id . "' AND attribute_id = '" . 28 . "' AND text = '" . $get_ves_item . "' AND text = '" . $get_meterial_item . "'";
```

то-есть добавить еще один AND, но что делать если этот параметр не будет получен? Как правильно сделать подскажите, пожалуйста.

```
if (isset($_POST['f__ves']) and isset($_POST['f__material'])) {
            echo "существует пост материал и есть вес";
            $get_ves = $_POST['f__ves'];  // Вес
            $get_material = $_POST['f__material'];  // Материал
            if ($product_id_arr) {
                foreach ($get_ves as $get_ves_item) {
                    foreach ($get_material as $get_ves_item) {
                    foreach ($product_id_arr as $prod_id) {

                     $prod_get_attr = "SELECT * FROM `oc_product_attribute` WHERE (product_id, attribute_id, text) in( ('" . $prod_id . "', 28, '" . $get_ves_item . "'), ('" . $prod_id . "', 29, '" . $get_materail_item . "') )"; // получаем id товаров, выбранных атрибутов Вес и материал
                     $query_prod_get_attr = mysqli_query($dbh, $prod_get_attr);
                     

                     foreach ($query_prod_get_attr as $product_id) {
                        $product_val[] = $product_id['product_id']; 
                    }
                    
                }
            
                
            }
            
            }
            var_dump($product_val);
        }
        }
```

Comment: напр. через foreach собирать запрос можно

Comment: Во первых - не использовать прямые запросы к БД. А так - твой запрос - это просто строка - можешь ее генерить в зависимости от того - задан ли параметр. Непонятно только - как поле text будет  соответствовать и весу и материалу

Comment: Таблица такого вида: |product_id| |atribute_id| |text|
Как будет соответствовать? тут я ошибся, скорее всего нужно делать отдельный sql запрос, так как у ves atribute_id = 28 а у material atribute_id = 29, вот незнаю как это сделать в рамках моего скрипта, нужно делать проверку на существование POST и делать еще foreach

Comment: Да, проверяйте какие параметры заданы и в зависимости от этого добавляйте в запрос нужные условия. И да, поле text одной и той же записи не может быть одновременно равно двум разным значениям, скорее всего вам понадобятся OR и group by для подсчета совпавших условий как тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/506498/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%bc/506507#506507

Comment: Посмотрите пожалуйста, сделал как вы сказали, но безуспешно

Comment: Помогите, плиз  ) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1155661/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%b2-%d0%b1%d0%b4-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f%d0%bc-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8f?noredirect=1#comment2003856_1155661