# Как правильно сделать запрос в бд для выбора по нескольким значениям одного поля

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Таблица такого вида:

```
|product_id| |atribute_id| | text  |
|     1    | |    28     | |золото |
|     1    | |    29     | |  255  |
|     2    | |    28     | |серебро|
|     2    | |    29     | |  111  |
|     3    | |    28     | |золото |
|     3    | |    29     | |  455  |
```

Есть Вес atribute_id = 29 и материал atribute_id = 28, данные text получаю из формы:

```
$get_ves = $_POST['f__ves'];  // Вес
$get_material = $_POST['f__material'];  // Материал
```

Нужно получить массив product_id, в соответсвии с полученными данными, к примеру получили Золото и 255 и 455, поэтому должны получить $product_id со значениями 1 и 3.
ПРобовал выполнить вот такой sql запрос:

```
"SELECT * FROM `oc_product_attribute` WHERE (product_id, attribute_id, text) in(('" . $prod_id . "', 28, '" . $get_ves_item . "'), ('" . $prod_id . "', 29, '" . $get_materail_item . "')) "
```

Но получил только фильтрацию по ('" . $prod_id . "', 28, '" . $get_ves_item . "') второй параметр IN не учелся почему то... ПОдскажите в чем проблема, заранее спасибо

Comment: У тебя в поле text. text = "золото 255" строковое значение ? полностью? а то по табличке которую ты нарисовал есть ряд золото и есть есть ряд 255. В общем как понимать text = "золото 255" или text = "золото" а в следующем ряду text = "255"???

Comment: поле text это строки!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас одно значение `Материал` и массив значений `Вес`, то:

```
SELECT product_id FROM oc_product_attribute
WHERE text IN ("золото", "серебро") AND product_id IN (
   SELECT product_id FROM oc_product_attribute 
   WHERE atribute_id = 29 AND text IN (255, 455)
) GROUP BY product_id
```

Comment: Материал может быть не одно значение, это я написал условно, эти данные приходят с филтра, там набор значений, пользователь может выбрать множество значений, (например материал, золото, серебро, а вес 233, 273, 432) И на основе этих данных нужно выбрать подходящие product_id

Comment: @ilyaaa521 Ну тогда `WHERE text = "золото"` заменить на `WHERE text IN ("золото", "серебро", ... )`

Comment: Спасибо, рабочий вариант! Можете подсказать, как получить теперь на основе полученного id получить данные из другой таблице? Я думаю тут нужно запрос дописать с LEFT JOIN? С join не работал просто ранее...

Comment: @ilyaaa521 если эта другая таблица - **product**, то с помощью **JOIN**, например:  `SELECT product.* FROM oc_product_attribute JOIN product ON product.id = oc_product_attribute.product_id`

Comment: Это другим запросом? Или можно в этом же?

Comment: @ilyaaa521 нет, почему другим, прямо в этом же.  `SELECT product.* FROM oc_product_attribute JOIN product ON product.id = oc_product_attribute.product_id WHERE oc_product_attribute.text IN ("золото", "серебро") AND oc_product_attribute.product_id IN (` А дальше все без изменений как было

Comment: ```SELECT oc_product.* FROM oc_product_attribute JOIN oc_product ON oc_product.id = oc_product_attribute.product_id WHERE oc_product_attribute.text IN ('" . $get_material_item . "') AND oc_product_attribute.product_id IN (SELECT product_id FROM oc_product_attribute
WHERE text IN ('" . $get_material_item . "') AND product_id IN (
   SELECT product_id FROM oc_product_attribute 
   WHERE atribute_id = 29 AND text IN ('" . $get_material_item . "')
) GROUP BY product_id;```

Comment: Я извиняюсь, мне нужно лучше изучить sql..

Comment: В смысле, не работает? Вроде правильно вы написали на первый взгляд

Comment: https://3v4l.org/Qk8LV , получаю Золотоbool(false)
bool(false)
bool(false)....

Comment: что-то у вас там внутри лишний селект, должно быть по идее вот так: https://3v4l.org/YkvrM

Comment: Да, и последняя строчка тоже это уже я ошибся, группировать же уже по другому полю нужно: https://3v4l.org/Tbbf2

Comment: Я сделал немного по другому, https://3v4l.org/vF8YV в базе руками если вставить значения то работает, переношу в php, получаю bool(false) почему то

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110939/discussion-between---and-ilyaaa521).