# Выборка из бд несколько знаений одного поля

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Нужно выбрать из базы нужные товары в зависимости от полученных данных формы:

```
if (isset($_POST['f__ves']) and isset($_POST['f__material'])) {
            echo "существует пост материал и есть вес";
            $get_ves = $_POST['f__ves'];  // Вес
            $get_material = $_POST['f__material'];  // Материал
            if ($product_id_arr) {
                foreach ($get_ves as $get_ves_item) {
                    foreach ($get_material as $get_material_item) {
                        foreach ($product_id_arr as $prod_id) {

                         $prod_get_attr = "SELECT * FROM `product_attribute` WHERE (product_id, attribute_id, text) in( ('" . $prod_id . "', 28, '" . $get_ves_item . "'), ('" . $prod_id . "', 29, '" . $get_materail_item . "') )"; // получаем id товаров, выбранных атрибутов Вес и материал
                         $query_prod_get_attr = mysqli_query($dbh, $prod_get_attr);
                         foreach ($query_prod_get_attr as $product_id) {
                            $product_val[] = $product_id['product_id']; 
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
                
                }
                var_dump($product_val);
            }
        }
```

Думаю ошибка в sql запросе, но не могу понять какая... Подскажите пожалуйста.
Таблица выглядит так:

```
|product_id| |atribute_id| | text  |
|     1    | |    28     | |золото |
|     1    | |    29     | |  255  |
|     2    | |    28     | |серебро|
|     2    | |    29     | |  111  |
|     3    | |    28     | |золото |
|     3    | |    29     | |  455  |
```

Нужно сделать выборку в данной таблице, получаю с формы вес и материал, например получили с формы вес 111, как правильно сделать запрос?

Comment: Первый раз вижу WHERE IN запрос по множественным колонкам ... Вы хоть документацию и примеры читали, или придумываете из головы?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/506498/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%bc/506507#506507

Comment: Я думаю лучше вообще не отвечать, чем как вы....

Comment: У вас идентификаторы (_id) в БД - не строки, попробуйте удалить для них кавычки. А для проверки правильности запроса всегда можно вставить тестовые данные и на них протестировать корректность SQL запроса.